# MySQL errors with php artisan migrate

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, ubuntu, database-migration

I am trying to **migrate** database with **php** and **laravel** ( using **UBUNTU 19** ), but got stuck with some **MySQL** errors :
First of all , i login with mysql CLI without root user ( with **"mysql"** command only )
then when i run:

```
php artisan migrate
```

it tells me :

> The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

i try then to login with root user ( using **"mysql -u root"** command ) and run
`php artisan migrate`    , again
this time , it tells me :

> Your password has expired. To log in you must change it using a client
> that supports expired passwords.

so i try to set password using

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

it shows up another error :

> You must reset your password using ALTER USER statement before
> executing this statement.

**(** changing password using

```
 SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('new_password')
```

generates SQL syntax error **)**

So i thought about setting password with the first login ( using "mysql" command only ) , but that tells me again :

> The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it
> cannot execute this statement

**I AM REALLY STUCK WITH THAT WHAT SHOULD I DO WITH IT ?**

Comment: remove permanently MySQL and reinstall again

Answer (score 0):

Create a new mysql user :

```
CREATE USER 'laravel'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Then provide new user access :

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to 'laravel'@'localhost';
```

Finally flush to reload all privileges:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now use new username and password in your configuration. The problem will be solved.

Comment: i logged in to mysql with root user and provided this new user access , it shows : "You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT" , i tried to log in with laravel user and then it shows "Access denied for user 'laravel'@'localhost'"